# Неприемлемы или не приемлемы?

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно

Такой вопрос задавался **на одном из форумов**: *Традиции питания, сложившиеся в тёплых странах, могут быть для нас **не приемлемы***. Корректно ли раздельное написание НЕ?  [Источник](https://rusforus.ru/viewtopic.php?t=12593)

Я считала,что краткие прилагательные на МЫЙ с НЕ пишутся **слитно**  по правилу [Розенталь, пункт 13](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77), но в Нацкорусе **раздельное** написание НЕ иногда (хотя и редко) встречается, причем в **современных** текстах.

Следует ли считать такую запись **ошибочной**? Или все-таки возможны **исключения** для отдельных слов? К тому же в одном из примеров есть **усиление** отрицания.

**Примеры**

Различные инициативы по стимулированию заповедников зарабатывать средства с помощью туризма **не приемлемы** (2013).

Для меня были **не приемлемы** манипуляции Горбачева с новым союзным договором («огаревский процесс») и его мнимое «затворничество» в Форосе (2011).

Естественно, ни бумага, ни ткани, ни краски **не приемлемы** в подземелье крепости: **ни эстетически, ни климатически** (2001).

Те методы, которыми это пытаются делать, для меня **не приемлемы** (2000).

Его трудности усугублялись тем, что те инструменты и сама система принуждения, к которым была приучена страна и на которых зиждился весь коммунистический порядок, были **уже не приемлемы** (1996).

**Для сравнения**: Наши правила сложны, многочисленны и для многих **неприемлемы** (2011).

Comment: *Разница такая: небыстрый – это почти медленный, не быстрый – средний. Это называется градацией признака* — где можно об этом почитать?

Comment: Не помню, давно это было. Наберите  в Интернете. А сами этого не понимаете?

Comment: Не особо понимаю, но что-то такое улавливаю. Но это не о значениях (оно не меняется), а об особенностях употребления. Не смогу найти, даже не знаю, как искать, вся надежда на вас.

Comment: Не, я пас, читала где-то давно.  Я до Розенталя все Валгину изучала, да и другие авторы были. И вообще, не могу  больше нести знания народу, никто не понимает. Про ударение точно никто ничего не понял – можно удалить, даже и не заметят.  Или найдут какую-то мелочь и бредом назовут. Так что пока, до новых встреч.  Ну и вопрос еще мой остался –-несите свой справочник, почитаем.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь сказуемое "могут быть" влияет.

*Могут быть какими?* || Вопрос, показывающий, что нужно одно слово как ответ. Отрицание здесь вообще не подходит.

В таких случаях требуется утверждение (слитное написание).

Что здесь происходит? Есть же принцип подстановки глаголов "быть"/"являться":
*быть неприемлимыми;

не быть приемлимыми*.
У нас "быть" имеется, оно указывает на написание.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139491/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd----).